# How can $0$ be an interior point of $[0,1]$ when $\mathbb R$ is given the discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb R$ be topologized with the discrete topology. Then every subset of $\mathbb R$ is clopen. So, for every $A \subset \mathbb R$, $\operatorname{int}(A)=A$.

But if $A=[0,1]$, the neighborhood of $0 \in A$ is not a subset of $A$. So how can $0$ (or $1$) be an interior point of $A$?

Comment: This has been discussed like 20 minutes ago?!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Certainly $\{0\}$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: Note that $x\in \text{int}(A)$ if $\exists U$, open, such that $x\in U\subseteq A$. With the discrete topology all sets are open so $0\in \{0\}\subseteq A$ proves $0\in \text{int}(A)$.

Comment: @guest If you think this question is a duplicate, you should vote to close it as such, but I cannot find the discussion you mention.

Comment: @5xum Apparently the OP deleted the question I refer to. In that question he asked for the usual topology instead of the discrete topology. But, many comments there said that the result is true with the discrete topology, so I wonder why delete the old question and re-ask this here.

Comment: @Guest I deleted b/c I asked the wrong question. Many comments there said the results was true? False. Only one comment mentioned discrete topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say

> The neighborhood of $0\in A$ is not a subset of $A$

This is false. Ask yourself: *what is a neighborhood*?

By definition, $X$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if $x\in X$ and $X$ is an open set.

Well, in your case, having discrete topoloygy, *EVERY* set is an open set, so $[0,1]$ is a neighborgood of $0$, and $\{0\}$ is also a neighborhood of $0$, and $[0,0.1]$ is also a neighborhood of $0$, and so is $[0,1)$.

Comment: A neighborhood of $0$ would be $(0-h,0+h)$ where $h >0$.

Comment: Just a note on terminology: Many (most?) authors do not require neighbourhoods to be open. Then any superset of an open neighbourhood is a neighbourhood.

Comment: @AlJebr No, by definition, a neighborhood of a point is an open set containing the point. A neighborhood *DEPENDS ON THE TOPOLOGY*, and in the discrete topology, $\{0\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: I think most authors define neighbourhood as *open* ...but haven't done a poll.

Answer (score 5):

If $\Bbb R$ has the discrete topology, then $\{0\}$ is an open set in $\Bbb R$ and hence in $A$.

Comment: A neighborhood of $0$ would be $(0-h,0+h)$ where $h >0$. So, how does there exists a neighborhood with such properties?

Comment: @AlJebr You're thinking euclidean. Under the *discrete* topology, **any** set is a neighbourhood of itself.

Comment: @AlJebr: That's a nbhd of $0$ in the usual (Euclidean) topology; in the discrete topology $\{0\}$ is an open nbhd of $0$.